# Xperia Z3 Rooting

Tags: rooting, sony-xperia, xposed-framework

Two days ago I upgraded my Xperia Z3 to Lollipop. Needless to say I'm not impressed (mainly due to no longer having great battery life), and plan on going back to 4.4 soon. For some time I've been wanting to root my phone in order to install the Xposed framework, however this would be my first time ever rooting, or flashing any roms on a phone. I have the D6603 model, and want to make sure whenever I root the phone I don't lose the DRM keys and ruin the phone's camera.

Are there any recommended guides or videos for someone brand new to rooting/flashing? I've looked around in the XDA forums, but I run into various threads on rooting, and have no idea what is safe, and what could potentially brick my phone.

Answer (score 0):

I have a favourite that is extremely quick, easy and simple.

It was called Vroot, now Iroot. It doesn't even require a PC!

http://www.mgyun.com/en/getvroot

Hope this helps!

Comment: Has anyone else used this?

Comment: Yes me and my parents and friends and it works really well!

Comment: Didn't work on Xperia Z3 Tablet Mini  (model SGP621 with Android 5.1.1).